# How to express "There is no largest negative real number."

Tags: number-theory, real-numbers, predicate-logic

Obviously, given you know how to write the statement "There is no largest real number," you can just use R≤0, which would be

> $\lnot \exists x \in \mathbb R_{\le 0}, \forall y \in \mathbb R_{\le 0}, y \leq x$

But if you just wanted to $\mathbb R$, how would you express it? Is $\lnot \exists x \in \mathbb R, \forall y \in \mathbb R, y \leq x < 0$ correct? I think it should be able to be expressed as such, but I am not sure...

Comment: My instinct is that if you used $<0$ rather than $\leq 0$ this would be clearer since $0$ can’t be positive or negative.

Comment: I’ve also seen $\mathbb{R}^{-}$ used for the negative real numbers.

Comment: $y\le x$ does not guarantee that we can always find a smaller real number. You have to use "<". You can simplify the thing as follows (I give the statement in plain text, you can transform it into an expression with quantifiers) : For every real number $x$ , there is a real number $y$ with $y<x$ (which implies that there is no smallest real number , which is the same as the largest (in absolute value) negative real number.

Comment: @Peter Oh ok, I just assumed it was $y \leq x$ because of this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2241055/923458

Answer (score 3):

The suggested formula is not quite right because it would also fail for $\mathbb Z$. The problem is that it fails because the placement of the $\forall y$ means that you are insisting every real $y$ is smaller than $x$, not just the negative ones. You could fix it by saying $$\neg\exists x\in\mathbb R\, (x<0)\wedge\forall y\in\mathbb R\, (y<0\Rightarrow y\leq x).$$

Comment: So by putting $< 0$ in front of $y$ and $x$, it does not mean "there is not a real number $x$ for all real numbers $y$ that makes all of the negative real numbers $y$ smaller than that $x$"? If I wanted to express what I just said I would have to go with your expression instead of $\lnot \exists x \in \mathbb R, \forall y \in \mathbb R, (y \leq x) < 0$?

Comment: @Curulian Your proposed formula in the comments doesn't have proper syntax. Normally $y\leq x<0$ is short for the conjunction $(y\leq x) \wedge (x<0),$ and if you interpret your formula literally with that correction it means "There does not exist an $x$ such that for every $y$, $y\leq x$ and $x<0$." In particular $y=x+1$ would satisfy that.